# Is there any plugin in wordpress which work like sobi2 in joomla?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Is there any plugin in wordpress  which work like sobi2 in joomla,like show listing,then click on particular list then detail page display of that list.
Hope some one help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a CCK, there are 2 that I know of -

Flutter - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fresh-page/
Pods - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/

Either one should work for a simple listing.